# WordPress permalinks - Google search results in 404 for valid page

Tags: .htaccess, permissions, wordpress, permalinks

I am using WordPress 3.0.4 (in the process of updating but stuck with 3.0.4 for now) with the day and name permalink structure.

The permalinks are working fine from within the site (i.e. clicking on a blog post from the main page) however when I search for a post in Google and click the link, I get a 404.

Copying the URL from the Google results and opening a new window or refreshing however sends me to the correct entry.

The URL format looks like this: http://www.mysite.com/blog/2012/02/08/title-of-post/

And .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have already tried renaming .htaccess and creating a new one, changing the .htaccess permissions, disabling all plugins, and using the default WordPress theme all with no luck.

Same problem here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/google-search-results-in-404-for-a-valid-page?replies=9 but looks like OP never found a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: URLs to live pages where this is occurring would help potential answerers in seeing the issue. Also, is that the default .htaccess configuration, or is it your modified version?